# How to Mocking CacheAsyncApi

Tags: scala, testing, redis, mocking, playback

I'm using **CacheAsyncApi** in my Scala class:

```
class AggregationService @Inject()(@NamedCache("name") cache: CacheAsyncApi){}
```

and I want to do a unit test for it.

so tried to do **FakeChache** with implement the CacheAsyncApi methods.

the problem is that I didn't succeed to implement the 'map' functionality :

the function should be as follow:

```
override def map[T](key: String)(implicit evidence$8: ClassTag[T]): RedisMap[T, AsynchronousResult] = ???
```

how you test your CacheAsyncApi functionality? And in particular the map functionality

build.sbt includes:

```
  lazy val playLibs = Seq(
    "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-cache" % "2.7.2",
    "com.github.karelcemus" %% "play-redis" % "2.4.0"
  )
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your version of the `map`? What are specific problems you have with implementing it?

Comment: hi @michaJlS!
that map is part of CacheApi of 'play-Redis' library, for other functionality of redis like get or set, I did tests already, but for the 'map' functionality of Redis (e.g hget/hset etc) its much more complicated.

[link for documentation of play-redis](https://github.com/KarelCemus/play-redis/blob/2.6.1/doc/30-how-to-use.md)

Comment: Do I understand that you wanted to implement this method in `FakeChache` but you've failed? If so then please share the code and error you got.
Instead of implementing own version you can use as well a mock lib like mockito or scalamock. I don't remember whether play has any preferences here.